# How to stop the relay after it is getting on and let the sensor get the result

Tags: arduino-mega, relay, loop

I want to provide a delay in the following iteration reading so that the sensor can read the condition after the pump starts.

```cpp
void loop() {
  //-------------Fungsi Read sensor----------- 
  // sensorAll();

  hasilec = (ppmcensor - inputec);
  ph = (phcensor - inputph);
  
  //  hasilec = random(-200, 0) / 100.0;
  //  ph = random(-200, 200) / 100.0;

  //  ph = -180/100.0;
  //  hasilec = -1.2;
  
  unsigned long now = millis();
  
  Serial.print("pH    ");
  Serial.print(ph);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("EC ");
  Serial.print(hasilec);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print(ph); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(hasilec); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(" ");

  //  delay (500000);
  
  fuzzy->setInput(2, hasilec);
  fuzzy->setInput(1, ph);  
  fuzzy->fuzzify();

  float pompa01 = fuzzy->defuzzify(1);//pHDOWN
  float pompa02 = fuzzy->defuzzify(2);//pHUP
  float pompa03 = fuzzy->defuzzify(3);//ABMIX
  
  Serial.println("Result= ");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print(" Pompa1 pHDOWN: ");
  Serial.println(pompa01);
  Serial.print(" pompa2 phUP  : ");
  Serial.println(pompa02);
  Serial.print(" pompa3 ABMIX : ");
  Serial.println(pompa03);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("");
  
  delay (2000);
  
  long int pompa1 = pompa01 * 1000;
  long int pompa2 = pompa02 * 1000;
  long int pompa3 = pompa03 * 1000;
  
  pump_periods[0] = pompa1; //PHdown
  pump_periods[1] = pompa2; //PHup
  pump_periods[2] = pompa3; //ABMIX
  
  for (int i = 0; i < jml_pump; i++) {
    if (now - pump_last_actuations[i] >= pump_periods[i]) {
      pump_states[i] = (pump_states[i] == LOW) ? HIGH : LOW;
      digitalWrite(pump_pins[i], pump_states[i]);
      pump_last_actuations[i] = now;
    }    
  }   
}
```

If I put the delay after millis iteration it causes the pump to only turn on based on the delay, not the timer millis. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What exactly keeps looping? The `loop()` function always loops, that is what is is meant for. Or what do you mean? And what does "not making space for my environment getting stabilize" mean?

Comment: why are you using fuzzy logic?

Comment: I mean let the wave pump mix all Ph and AB mix, and fet stabilize on set point, because im trying using fuzzy for it

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you said

Comment: Please [edit] you question and provide some context. If would help if you translate your variables and texts, too.

Comment: You can't put a large delay() anywhere in the loop without messing up the millis() timing you use in your for loop when pump_periods[i] are smaller than your delay. Please explain what needs to wait for what; what sensor reads what condition; what makes the pump start and where in the code that happens.

Comment: i want to wait a couple of minute for let the liquid mixed after im adding some pH up or down and AB-mix, the sensor read a ppm and pH and i got the value of them,the pump start base on my fuzzy rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the pumps have to work for `pump_periods[i]` time on every loop, and you will have a long `delay()` anyway, you could replace the `for` loop with:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < jml_pump; i++) { // For every pump:
  digitalWrite(pump_pins[i], 1);     // Start pump i
  delay(pump_periods[i]);            // Wait for pump_periods[i] ms
  digitalWrite(pump_pins[i], 0);     // Stop pump i
}
delay(120000);                       // Wait 2 minutes until mixed
```

This will block the loop, but you will have a long delay anyway. The pumps will work sequentially, and not at the same time.

Is that what you want?